# Split a sf line by spatial criteria

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

I have a sf object composed by lines. I can split each group of segments by an attribute (for example by date, using attribute table, black and blue lines in the image) but segments with the same date located in different areas are incorrectly connected as in the attached image.
I would like to split segments by a spatial criteria (for example forcing splits if the distance is more than 100 meters between following rows of the AT). How can I do?

[image: lines by date]

Comment: You can draw a buffer around lines with `sf::st_buffer()` and then check with `sf::st_contains()` whether the buffer contains the subsequent line.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but what is the advantage to make a buffer starting with the lines that have already the wrong connections? Perhaps the reasoning is not wrong... Maybe it could be useful to apply buffers to the points and then, in some way, split lines where the buffers do not merge...

Comment: In your question, you mention that you would like to split a line, if it diverges by more than 100 meters from subsequent lines. You can do that by creating a buffer around one of the lines and cutting lines with `st_intersection` and `st_difference`. Before you apply `st_intersection` and `st_difference`, you can check with `st_contains` whether the lines diverge by more than 100 meters at all, i.e. whether any split is required.